# Ajax post value to secondary page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to post the value of a drop down box to a secondary page through ajax but am getting nothing. I have had a look at some similar issues on here but none really match even though I tried their solutions. The **dropdown id** is `email_select` and the **url** I want it sent to is correct. Many apologies but Google isn't helping as much as I'd like. :)

```
$j(function() {
  $j(document).on('change', 'select#email_select', function(event) {
    $j.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../profile/ajax/email_info.php",
        data: {#select_email val(),
        },
        cache: false,
        alert('error');
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: your data parameter is wrong. It should be like `data: {'email':$('#select_email').val(),` and you have to use email as parameter to fetch the value in your php page

Comment: use `$("#select_email").val()` instead of `#select_email val()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#select_email val()` means nothing,

Your target is `select#mail_select` ,
You should do :

```
 var data = $('select#email_select').val()
 $j.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../profile/ajax/email_info.php",
    data: {'mydata' :data},
    cache: false
  });
```

Check the documentation and see the examples at the bottom
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thats great thank you and thanks to everyone who answered :)

Answer (score 1):

The way you are sending ajax request payload data is not correct. Try this

```
 var data = $('#email_select').val()
 $j.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../profile/ajax/email_info.php",
    data: {'email' :data},
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
    }
  });
});
```